# Alternatives to Horvitz–Thompson estimator

Tags: estimation, sample

I am trying to estimate a mean of a population in a sample = ${\{x_1,..,x_n\}}$. I currently use 2 estimators:

1. Sample mean  = $\frac{\sum {x_i}}{n} $
2. Horvitz–Thompson estimator (HT)  =  $\frac{\sum {p_i*x_i}}{\sum {p_i}} $

Where
$p_i$ is the probability that the value$(x_i)$ is part of the sample during the sampling

Note that it is a sampling with replacement, so there could be more than one $x$ that have the same value, i.e. value($x_1$) =  value($x_5$) = 7

The HT estimator performed better than sample mean in my experiments. But for some samples, $p_i$ is unknown.

So my questions are

1. Are there alternatives to HT estimator? (such as other estimators that use weighting scheme based on sample only)
2. Let's say I just know that the sample is from a sampling with replacement but don't know exactly how a sample is taken (e.g. someone gives me the sample and ask me to estimate the mean of the population.) and I want to use HT estimator. Can I approximate $p_i$ based on a frequency that the value($x_i$) appears in the sample? For example

   $p_i$ = $\frac{\#\text{value($x_i$) in a sample}}{n} $

Thank you!

Comment: What *do* you know, or can reasonably assume, about how the samples were taken? After all, someone could have picked the $n$ lowest values of $x$ from the population.

Comment: I know the sampling processes (they are modified random walks on graphs) but some of them are so complicated that I can't compute $p_i$ (or a stationary distribution in my case)

Comment: I think you'll need to provide some detail to get an answer, if there is one. In general, if you want to know how well a sample statistic performs as an estimator of a population parameter, you need to know how the sample is taken from the population.

Comment: I edited my question. Since I can't compute the $p_i$ so in my question, I assume that I don't know exactly how a unit is sampled. All I know is that it is from a sampling with replacement.